# Random generator test. Where is error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, random

Strange tests behaviour.
I have class that generate random values.

```
std::random_device RandomProvider::rd;
std::mt19937 RandomProvider::rnb(RandomProvider::rd());
    #define mainDataType unsigned int

mainDataType RandomProvider::GetNextValue(mainDataType upperLimit)
{
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, upperLimit);
    return uniform_dist(rnb);
}
```

And unit-test that test it's behavior.

```
    TEST_METHOD(TestRandomNumber)
    {
        CreateOper(RandomNumber);
        int one = 0, two = 0, three = 0, unlim = 0;
        const int cycles = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
        {
            mainDataType res = RandomProvider::GetNextValue(3);
            if (res == 1) one++;
            if (res == 2) two++;
            if (res == 3) three++;
        }

        double onePerc = one / (double)cycles;
        double twoPerc = two / (double)cycles;
        double threePerc = three / (double)cycles;

        Assert::IsTrue(onePerc > 0.20 && onePerc < 0.40);
        Assert::IsTrue(twoPerc > 0.20 && twoPerc < 0.40);
        Assert::IsTrue(threePerc > 0.20 && threePerc < 0.40);
    }
```

Test passed all-times in debug and if i chose it and Run only it. But it fails all times when i
run it with other tests. I added debug output to text file and got unreal values onePerc =  0.0556, twoPerc= 0.0474 and threePerc = 0.0526... What is going on here? (i am using VS2013 RC)

Comment: As you already have noticed, those three numbers don't add up to 1.0. Can you verify the final values of `one`, `two`, `three` and `cycles`?

Comment: one=556
two=474
three=526
unlim=526 (not is one or two or three)
cycles=10000

Comment: don't understand what is it.... memory problem or VS problem... in single solution with one test ..all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a static `uniform_int_distribution` the first time you call `GetNextValue` the max limit is set, never being changed in any subsequent call. Presumably in the test case you mentioned, your first call to `GetNextValue` had a different value than `3`. Judging from the values returned it looks like probably either 19 or 20 was used in the first such call.